# Javascript: calling object function/method from onclick event, with dynamic argument

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, onclick, invoke

I'm trying to do this:

```
<script>
var MyItem;

MyItem = new myobj('testobj');

function myobj(id)
{
     var _id = id;

     this.toggle = function()
     {
       ...
     }

     function draw()
     {
         document.body.innerHTML += "<a onclick='" + MyItem + ".toggle();'>link</a>";
     }

     draw();

}
</script>
```

I get "function is not defined", but can invoke MyItem.toggle() from console successfully. I've also tried:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<a onclick='(function(){" + MyItem + ".toggle();})()'>link</a>";
```

The anchor has to be dynamically created in javascript. How do I invoke the MyItem object method toggle() from the dynamically created anchor?

ps, I'm typing js from memory, so if there are syntax errors I apologise.

Comment: You're outputting a String; this makes no sense. You need to output the name of your variable in that string... if that's really the way you want to do this.

Comment: You're right. Should have been ... _id + '.toggle()'... ID always = obj instance name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not add event handlers and elements like that. Use DOM methods

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.innerHTML = "link";
anchor.onclick = function(){ MyItem.toggle(); };
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
```

I actually think you are after something like this

```
var MyItem;

MyItem = new myobj('testobj');

function myobj(id) {
    var that = this;
    this.toggle = function () {
        alert(id);
    }
    function draw() {
        var anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.innerHTML = "link";
        anchor.onclick = function () {
            that.toggle();
        };
        document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    }
    draw();
}
```

Comment: Your absolute right about the method, but the MyItem object is only available as a string stored in the _id property. How would you add that to the onclick event?

Comment: Why do you have to assign that=this?

Answer (score 2):

That won't work.  You are trying to use an object like a string. Try the following:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<a onclick='(function(){MyItem.toggle();})()'>link</a>";
```